# Generating a list of all self-signed certs for multiple machines in an enviroment?

Tags: powershell, security, network-programming

I am trying to generate a list of all the self-signed certificates in an environment using Powershell.

I need this section of my script ( shown below ) to be directed toward multiple machines(IP addresses), but am unaware of how to do so:

```
dir cert: -Recurse |
where {$_.subject -ne $null} |
where {$_.subject -eq $_.issuer} |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -delimiter ';' -path .\ssc_export
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a list of all self-signed certs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104830/generating-a-list-of-all-self-signed-certs)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Invoke-Command with scriptblock parameter ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6

```
Invoke-Command -Computer <RemoteMachine> -ScriptBlock { <Your script here> }
```