# Generating a list of all self-signed certs?

Tags: encryption, certificate

I am trying to generate a list of all self-signed certificates in an environment using Powershell.

I need this section of my script to be directed toward multiple machines(IP addresses), but am unaware of how to do so:

```
dir cert: -Recurse |
where {$_.subject -ne $null} |
where {$_.subject -eq $_.issuer} |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -delimiter ';' -path .\ssc_export
```

Powershell isn't my strong suit, but it's all I have available to me in this environment. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [WinRM is configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management) and you have the required permissions this would work:

```bsh
$computers = Get-Content -Path "R:\computers.txt"

$Results = @()

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
  $Results += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { 

    $storeNames = @();
    foreach($store in Get-ChildItem -Path "cert:CurrentUser" `
      | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne 'UserDS' } ` # filter UserDS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116536/powershell-fails-when-trying-to-read-certificate-store-with-the-specified-netwo/57278095#57278095
    ){
      $storeNames += "cert:CurrentUser\$($store.Name)";
    }
    foreach($store in Get-ChildItem -Path "cert:LocalMachine"){
      $storeNames += "cert:LocalMachine\$($store.Name)";
    }

    $storeNames | % { Get-ChildItem -Path $_ } `
    | where {$_.subject -ne $null} `
    | where {$_.subject -eq $_.issuer} `
    | select-object -property `
        @{ Name="Computer"; Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME} }, `
        @{ Name="Path"; Expression={$_.PSParentPath} }, `
        @{ Name="Subject"; Expression={$_.Subject} }, `
        @{ Name="Issuer"; Expression={$_.Issuer} } `
    | Format-Table
  };       
}

$Results
```